# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, email, attachment

I have an asp.net website and I allready did .Dispose() here is my code below;

> try
>           {
>
> ```
>         MailMessage newMail = new MailMessage(MailFrom, MailTo,
> ```
>
> MailSubject, MailMsg);
>
> ```
>         if (MailAttachment != "")
>         {
>             Attachment data = new Attachment(MailAttachment,
> ```
>
> MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
>                   newMail.Attachments.Add(data);
>               }
>               newMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
>               newMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
>
> ```
>         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("192.168.2.205");
>         client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
>         client.Send(newMail);
>
>         newMail.Attachments.Dispose();
>         newMail.Dispose();
>
>         DeleteAttachment(MailAttachment);
>
>         lblSuccess.Text = "Başvurunuz alınmıştır teşekkürler.";
>         lblSuccess.Visible = true;
>         ClearForm();
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         lblSuccess.Text = ex.Message;
>         //lblSuccess.Text = "Bir sorun oluştu bir daha deneyiniz.";
>         lblSuccess.Visible = true;
>     }
> ```

But i' m getting the same error, it' s running fine in my localhost but in server i' m getting this error. How can i fix it?

Comment: Perhaps it's being used by another process?

Try providing a bit more information.

Comment: maybe A larger code snippet will help

Comment: I edited and give a larger code snippet hope it will be helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call dispose on the Attachment object.

Calling Dispose on the SmtpClient, doesn't call it on the Attachments.

Comment: Did you call data.Dispose()? Or just on the attachments collection? Try it on the individual attachment.  If that doesn't work, the other thing you can do, is read the file into a byte array, and create the attachment from the byte array.

Comment: btw, here is a codesnippet to help:             
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\temp\\sample.jpg");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( data );
            Attachment a = new Attachment(ms, "sample.jpg");
            m.Attachments.Add(a);
            File.Delete("c:\\temp\\sample.jpg");